# SQL query to pass the column names dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a select query in a stored procedure which is getting the column list as a parameter. Passing the column list as a parameter uses quotes `''`. I want to remove the quotes when passing it to the query.

How to remove the single quotes of the dynamic column list using a SQL query?

For example Table is:

```
id  string  value
1    ttt    111
2    ggg    222
```

Stored Procedure:

```
--Exec sp_dc 'id,String'
alter proc sp_dc
(
    @Col_list nvarchar(255)
)
as
begin
    select Replace(@Col_list, '''', '') from table
end
```

When I execute the below query:

```
Exec sp_dc 'id,String'
```

I should get the result:

```
id  string
1    ttt
2    ggg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace` function:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) = '''col1'', ''col2'''
SELECT @s
SELECT REPLACE(@s, '''', '')
```

This should be in your stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + Replace(@Col_list, '''', '')  + ' FROM table'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response how to use replace for the values @s have the values 'col1,col2' instead of '''col1'',''col2'''

Comment: @user2514925, absolutely the same way

Comment: but it displays the string col1,col2 instead of the values